# What does this sentence exactly mean? “like the s**t you are”

Tags: grammar, idioms

I don’t know what exactly the *like* + *the* + noun + *you are* structure stands for. In a movie I watched (Fallen Angels, 1996), the main character cursed someone by saying:

> I will flush you down the pan like the shit you are.

I don’t know what she meant by that, and would like to learn what it is.

Comment: add your research for "like the shit you are".

Comment: I actually googled it before asking, but there wasn’t a single post about this structure :/

Comment: @lbf googling gives hits of the same quote but without any grammar discussion. What did you intend by suggesting a search?

Comment: 'You are shit' and 'I will flush you down the pan' are combined in the extended (though made rather messy by the switch to a simile) metaphor 'I will flush you down the pan like the shit you are.'

Answer (score 2):

This is not an idiom. Its meaning is made up directly of the elements it is made of. But the construction and vocabulary may have confused things.

More explicitly:

> 'like the shit you are' <- 'like the shit that you are'

A certain event may happen, namely flushing down the pan... (a pan is not usually used for flushing, that is the one thing I don't get about this sentence. A toilet is what one usually what one flushes things down.)

So this event, the flushing may happen. How does it happen? It happens *like* something else, that is like flushing. Often one flushes shit. 'Like' here is the preposition that is for metaphors/similes. They are saying that you are like shit, or really that you *are* shit, and comparing the flushing of you to this shit, *which you are*.

Putting the 'that you are' at the end doesn't really add much meaning, it just lengthens the insult and puts the emphasis interestingly. To give a different example with the same syntax but different vocabulary:

> That woman acts confidently, like the politician that she is.

Same structure, different nouns/adjectives.

Comment: Isn't "pan" slang for toilet? *A typical flush toilet is a [ceramic bowl (pan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet) connected on the "up" side to a cistern (tank) that enables rapid filling with water,* (Wiki)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've never heard of 'pan' before as slang for a toilet (AmE). And it didn't evoke 'bedpan' for me.

Comment: "Down the pan" is BrE, certainly. See [Oxford 1.3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pan)

Answer (score 1):

It roughly stands for, "**like** [one does with] **the shit** [that] **you are**". So it means, "like we do with shit, because that's what you are".

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and accurate answer ^. ^ I still don’t know how to use it, but at least now I know what it means.

Comment: I think "the shit" (and not "the shits" which carries positive connotations) stands for.... the [piece of] shit [that] you are...